# Running ASP.Net Web Api inside intranet - cert authority invalid

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate

I made simple API for which is running on my "server" inside local network. When I want to call api from another PC  internet browser inside my intranet over https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100/ShowList i get warning from my browser that my connection is not private NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. I can proceed as unsafe but i would like to avoid that. The question is what I have to do to have save connection inside my intranet? I'm totally new in that so i'm aware of thing I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a ssl certificate to the hosting IIS server (assuming you are using IIS as the server). You can create a Self-Signed Certificate, buy from the vendors or use free services. Take a look at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis